# Convert an SQL statement into LINQ-To-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

can I get a hand converting the following into a LINQ statement.

```
SELECT reports.* FROM [dbo].[ReportLists] rl
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ReportItems] ri ON rl.Id = ri.ReportListId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Reports] reports ON ri.Id = reports.ReportItemId
WHERE
    reports.createdDate
IN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(report_max_dates.createdDate) 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Reports] report_max_dates
    GROUP BY 
        report_max_dates.seedLot
    )
```

Currently I have it down to this:

```
db.ReportLists.Select(rl => db.ReportItems
                            .Where(ri => ri.ReportListId == rl.Id)
                            .Select(ri => db.Reports
                                          .Where(r => r.ReportItemId == ri.Id)
                                          .GroupBy(r => new { r.seedLot })
                                          .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdDate).FirstOrDefault())));
```

The problem with the LINQ above is that it returns entries that have titles changed. Within the database I keep history of all records (hence the need for the first on the createdDate order descending. When I change a report from title x to title y, it shows up under both titles when I only want the most recent record which would hence be the one under title y.

**EDIT**
Sorry for the lack of detail. I have a reports table which holds info about the report (seedlot being an identifier). Whenever a report is edited, a new record is inserted (vs updating the old one) such that history is kept. In this case then the max entry for the createdDate indicates that the report is the most recent record to be displayed. Reports are then grouped into titles or ReportItems. These report items hold the title and associated reports. These reportItems are held in a ReportList such that I can print out the JSON in a desired format and just contains a status column and id linked to by the ReportItems.

In the event that a report is moved from title a to title b, a new record is entered with the title foreign key linking up to the title it was changed to. When this happens the above given LINQ returns the record under each individual ReportItem when it should only return the newest entry for title b (from the example above). Other than this the LINQ statement only returns the most recent record for the createdDate.

Here are my class structures (which mimic the DB structure as well)

```
public class ReportList {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string status {get;set;}
    public List<ReportItem> {get;set;}
}

public class ReportItem {
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string title {get;set;}
    public List<Report> {get;set;}
}

public class Report {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Lot {get;set;}
    ... Other data ...
    public DateTime createdDate {get;set;}
}
```

Thanks,
Dman

Comment: So am I correct in understanding that seed_lot is what differentiates truly distinct reports from one another *and* reports that have encountered a name change? That is, as far as report_max_dates goes, a renamed report isn't different from truly distinct (unrelated) reports?

Comment: Please give more detail. Explain what you want. It is hard to infer that from a SQL snippet and a faulty linq query. And explain how you the various versions of one report are kept together.

Comment: It appears to me you need to traverse a chain of update records to obtain the *latest* version of a report based on its seed_lot at incarnation, which may make the LINQ version of this (much?) more difficult than it may seem initially.

Comment: The inner LINQ of what I have provided for just reports works fine without adding in the report under each title. It's once I begin to retrieve the title (reportItems to reports) that it gives me the record under each vs just the latest record. The LINQ I provided gives the report list with appropriate reportItems but it gives me a record for each title if a report has had a title change vs just the recent record under the single title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the database schema to sorta flatten it out a bit a take out a lot of the branching.

Report is now the root and I just have a table of titles that get attached to the reports.

Thanks to all for the suggestions tho!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, then you want latest report by seedLot, then I'd use next:

```
from r in Reports
group r by r.CreateDate into g
select g.OrderByDescending(r1=>r1.CreateDate).FirstOrDefault()
```

Not quite sure why do you need ReportItem and ReportList if you do not include them into result, by you can traverse up to them with Report's navigational properties.

Comment: I need the ReportList and ReportItems such that the JSON object is formatted as required by the receiving end. My inner most LINQ statement already does this.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I see. Your Inner Join is culling out those records that have no Id in the ReportItems table and ReportItems that have no Id in the ReportLists table. Since you're not using inner join syntax in Linq, they aren't equivalent. Have you tried this:

```
var reports = from rl in db.ReportLists
              from ri in rl.ReportItems 
              from r in ri.Reports
              where (
                  from report in db.Reports
                  group report by report.seedLot into g
                  select g.Max(rep => rep.createdDate)).Contains(r.CreatedDate)
              select rl;
```

I'm not 100% that I've got the syntax right on that group with Contains (I don't do a lot of grouping day-to-day). And if the LINQ provider doesn't support the Max (or Contains, though it should) then it'll pull eveything client-side and that's a lot of data to push over the wire.

Comment: Sorry this statemen doesn't do exactly what I require. Although they do return the top reports without duplicates (my inner linq statement does that already as well) what I need is the reports returned in a reportItem under their respective title, not as a list of reports, but as a reportList, which contains all the reportItems, which then contains all their respective reports for that title.

Comment: Ah. All you have to do is change the return to rl instead of r.

Comment: Still not quite :( . This returns 6 report lists (one for each report). What I need is one report list, which contains 2 reportItems (since I have 2 titles) which each contain 3 reports (since I have 3 reports under each title) NOTE those values are specific to how I currently have the DB set up and will change as more data goes in/changes. Thank you very much for the continued effort tho!

Comment: Hmmm. Wonder if we didn't make things too complicated. Let's try something else. Updated the statement to simply have multiple froms. Note that each subsequent "from" uses the sub-object of the previous (so ri is drawn from rl.ReportItems instead of db.ReportItems).

Comment: This returns the same as the previous statement you had changed. Again thanks for the continued effort. I have a work around ATM (just get the reportList and ReportItems, then call a working statement to get only the reports under each title and insert them in the appropriate reportItem (it's ugly hence why I was trying to find one LINQ statement to do it).

Answer (score 0):

The details you provide make it much clearer, although not entirely, so I'll give two alternatives. The navigation properties come in handy, as now very concise comprehensive syntax is possible:

```
from rl in context.ReportLists
from ri in rl.ReportItems
from r in ri.Reports
group r by r.Lot into g
select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdDate).FirstOrDefault()
```

or (since you seem to group by `Title` in `ReportItems`):

```
from rl in context.ReportLists
from ri in rl.ReportItems
group ri by ri.Title into g
select g.Select(x => x.Reports
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.createdDate).FirstOrDefault())
```

under the hood this also produces SQL joins, but you don't need the awkward syntax. In linq fluent syntax it boils down to `SelectMany()`s.

As you see, I still can't figure out the role of `Lot` and `Title` but I hope the alternatives will give some substance to mould to your own specifications.

Comment: sorry these statements don't do exactly what I require. Although they do return the top reports without duplicates (my inner linq statement does that already as well) what I need is the reports returned in a reportItem under their respective title, not as a list of reports, but as a reportList, which contains all the reportItems, which then contains all their respective reports for that title (which have the max date).

Comment: If you want collections to be populated partly you need [`DataLoadOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534361), esp. `AssociateWith`. Or you should create bi-directional navigation properties so you can get the reportItem and reportList back through the report.