# Converting SQL Statement to LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on ASP.Net MVC4 application with EF , I am working to write my queries . I still exploring linq !

This is my SQL Statement : where I have 7 table to make join between them :: Date , Student, Task,  Timing , Assign ,SousType,TypeT

```
select  type ,  from Date , Student, Task,  Timing , Assign ,SousType,TypeT 
where DateT.ID_Date=Timing.ID_Date and Timing.ID_Timing = Assign.ID_Assign and Assign.ID_Student=Student.ID_Student 
and Assign.ID_Task= Task.ID_Task and Task.ID_SousType = SousType.ID_Sousype and SousType.ID_TypeT = TypeT.ID_Type ;
```

I started converting it step by step , but I could go further ,

```
   var students = from s in db.student
                      select s;
   IQueryable<Assign> mylist = db.Assign.Where(s => s.ID_Student == students.ID_student);
```

But I couldn't keep dealing in the same way to verify ID of every table since I got " IQueryable " .

Am I in the right way !!

Comment: One advice: try to use [navigation properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12326327/861716) in your linq statements like `student.Assigns` (or whatever). EF will do the joins for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out LINQ 101, there's a dedicated join operator: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

Comment: people prefer join just for less than 3 tables , but in this case ,we prefer to go one by one ! this is what they ve told us

Comment: IQueryable is a form of defered execution. The statements you wrote won't actually do anything until you access the result (by enumerating or FirstOrDefault or ToList etc.). I don't know who these people are, but a join is the most efficient :). Or is this homework and perhaps my solution doesn't cover this part of the course :)?

Comment: Perhaps start of by fixing your SQL statement, so that you have that working and then have a look at LinqPad (application for converting between SQL and LINQ). And have a look at the LINQ 101 examples for a better understanding of LINQ.